# Text File Writing Performance in Delphi

Tags: performance, delphi, file-io, delphi-xe2

My program is processing incoming strings (from Telnet, HTTP, etc), and I have to write these to a text file with Delphi XE2 for logging purposes.

Sometimes the program may crash and I need to be sure that the remaining strings are not lost so I open/close the file for every incoming string and I have some performance problems. The code below, for example, takes 8 seconds to complete.

My code is included below, is there some way to improve the performance?

(For the test below simply create a Form with a `Button : Button1`, with `OnClick` event and a `Label : lbl1`).

```
Procedure AddToFile(Source: string; FileName :String);
var
  FText : Text;
  TmpBuf: array[word] of byte;
Begin
  {$I-}
  AssignFile(FText, FileName);
  Append(FText);
  SetTextBuf(FText, TmpBuf);
  Writeln(FText, Source);
  CloseFile(FText);
  {$I+}
end;

procedure initF(FileName : string);
Var  FText : text;
begin
  {$I-}
  if FileExists(FileName) then  DeleteFile(FileName);
  AssignFile(FText, FileName);
  ReWrite(FText);
  CloseFile(FText);
  {$I+}
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tTime : TDateTime;
    iBcl : Integer;
    FileName : string;
begin
  FileName := 'c:\Test.txt';
  lbl1.Caption := 'Go->' + FileName; lbl1.Refresh;
  initF(FileName);
  tTime := Now;
  For iBcl := 0 to 2000 do
    AddToFile(IntToStr(ibcl) + '   ' +  'lkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj' , FileName);
  lbl1.Caption  :=  FormatDateTime('sss:zzz',Now-tTime);
end;
```

Comment: Opening/closing file is a time consuming operation. Why not to open it once, and keep file pointer somewhere in memory? Also possible lag can be in text files usage, try to use TFileStream and write data via blocks of bytes. To be sure that data is pushed to file, use FileStream.Flush

Comment: you should keep the file open once you've initialized it and either pass the FText variable around or keep it as a global variable...

Comment: It seems to me you are treating a symptom not a cause... Find out where the crash occurs put try ... except block around it and deal with the file closing there - then re-raise the exception if you are dead at that point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter), which is automatically buffered, and can handle flushing its buffers to the `TFileStream` automatically. It also allows you to choose to append to an existing file if you need to, set character encodings for Unicode support, and lets you set a different buffer size (the default is 1024 bytes, or 1K) in its various overloaded [`Create`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter.Create) constructors.

(Note that flushing the `TStreamWriter` only writes the content of the `TStreamBuffer` to the `TFileStream`; it doesn't flush the OS file system buffers, so the file isn't actually written on disk until the `TFileStream` is freed.)

Don't create the StreamWriter every time; just create and open it once, and close it at the end:

```
function InitLog(const FileName: string): TStreamWriter;
begin
  Result := TStreamWriter.Create(FileName, True);
  Result.AutoFlush := True;         // Flush automatically after write
  Result.NewLine := sLineBreak;     // Use system line breaks
end;

procedure CloseLog(const StreamWriter: TStreamWriter);
begin
  StreamWriter.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  tTime : TDateTime;
  iBcl : Integer;
  LogSW: TStreamWriter;
  FileName: TFileName;
begin
  FileName := 'c:\Test.txt';
  LogSW := InitLog(FileName);
  try
    lbl1.Caption := 'Go->' + FileName; 
    lbl1.Refresh;
    tTime := Now;

    For iBcl := 0 to 2000 do
      LogSW.WriteLine(IntToStr(ibcl) + '   ' +  'lkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj');

    lbl1.Caption  :=  FormatDateTime('sss:zzz',Now - tTime);
  finally
    CloseLog(LogSW);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TStreamWriter` does not flush OS file buffers; also it does not allow setting its own buffer size that makes it useless if performance is required.

Comment: @Serg: It *does* allow setting it's own buffer size. Check the documentation; it's done by using either of a couple of versions of the overloaded constructor (which I said in my answer above). See the linked documentation. It also does flush the OS buffers - see the docs on `AutoFlush`. Maybe you're used to an older version of StreamWriter?

Comment: Sorry, missed the overloaded constructor. Forgot what I said about the buffer size. :)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what the problem is with my answer?

Comment: Note the updated answer related to AutoFlush and its functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reopening file  to save critical data on disk you can either use [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or open a file for unbuffered I/O by calling the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flags (see `Remarks` section in the first link).

Comment: The alignment requirements for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` means that it is not very practical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it is practical if you do buffering yourself; the data if either written to disk or in your buffer.

Comment: That's the bit that's not very practical. Having to write that buffering code. May as well do `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`, or `FlushFileBuffers`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your problem is that you need to flush the cache after each write so that you won't lose data if your application crashes.

Whereas I'm sure the other answers here are excellent, you needn't make such extensive changes to your code.  All you need to do is call  `Flush(FText)`  after each write.

```
const
  // 10 million tests
  NumberOfTests = 1000000;

  // Open and close with each write:        19.250 seconds

  // Open once, and flush after each write:  5.686 seconds

  // Open once, don't flush                  0.439 seconds

var
  FText : Text;
  TmpBuf: array[word] of byte;

procedure initF(FileName : string);
begin
  {$I-}
  if FileExists(FileName) then  DeleteFile(FileName);
  AssignFile(FText, FileName);
  ReWrite(FText);
  SetTextBuf(FText, TmpBuf);
  {$I+}
end;

procedure CloseTheFile;
begin
  CloseFile(FText);
end;

Procedure AddToFile(Source: string);
Begin
  {$I-}
  Writeln(FText, Source);

  // flush the cache after each write so that data will be written
  // even if program crashes.
  flush ( fText );              // <<<====   Flush the Cache after each write

  {$I+}
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tTime : TDateTime;
    iBcl : Integer;
    FileName : string;
begin
  FileName := 'c:\Test.txt';
  lbl1.Caption := 'Go->' + FileName; lbl1.Refresh;
  initF(FileName);

  // put file close in a try/finally block to ensure file is closed
  // even if an exception is raised.
  try

    tTime := Now;
    For iBcl := 0 to NumberOfTests-1 do
      AddToFile(IntToStr(ibcl) + '   ' +  'lkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj');
    lbl1.Caption  :=  FormatDateTime('sss:zzz',Now-tTime);

  finally
    CloseTheFile;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: By the way, `Rewrite` will empty the file if it already exists, so there is no need to delete the file first.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason a simple reading from one text file and writing to text output file I found the TextFile WriteLn is still the fastest way.

```
  AssignFile(t,'c:\a\in.csv');
  Reset(t);
  AssignFile(outt,'c:\a\out.csv');
  ReWrite(outt);
  while not eof(t) do
  begin
    Readln(t,x);
    WriteLn(outt, x);   //27 sec, using LogSW.WriteLine(outx) takes 54 sec
```

// half Gb file took 27 sec with the above code, using TStreamWriter from example provided by Martijn took 54 seconds :o

Comment: not really related but FYI, same code in C# takes 14 sec.

                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(location + "\\" + singleFilename);
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFolder + "\\" + singleFilename);