# TStreamWriter (Auto)Flush does not?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Despite what is said in [Text File Writing performances in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306752/text-file-writing-performances-in-delphi) (comments under Ken White's answer), I see the TStreamWriter **not** flushing with the following code:

```
procedure TFrmAddEvents.LogEvent(AEvent: TcxSchedulerEvent);
begin
   if not Assigned(FStreamWriter) then
   begin
      FStreamWriter := TStreamWriter.Create(TFileStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.log'),fmCreate or fmOpenRead));
      FStreamWriter.AutoFlush := true;
   end;
   FStreamWriter.WriteLine(TcxEventDescription(AEvent));
   // Even this has no effect:
   FStreamWriter.Flush;
end;
```

Even after executing the

```
if Assigned(FStreamWriter) then FStreamWriter.Free;
```

in FormClose, the file is still 0 bytes.
When the program has finished executing, the file is 600+ kB.

- FStreamWriter is a form property of type TStreamWriter.
- Creating with `fmCreate or fmOpenWrite` makes no difference.
- TcxEventDescription does give a valid return string > 500 bytes containing CRLFs.
- As you can see I don't do anything with Encoding, all default Unicode stuff.
- I'm running from the Delphi XE2 IDE or as a standalone executable.
- 32 bit app under Win7 64bit

What can be going on and how to fix?

[Edited 7. Jan 2014]

Updated code after Uwe's answer; still does not work:

```
procedure TFrmAddEvents.LogEvent(AEvent: TcxSchedulerEvent);
var lName: string;
begin
   lName := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.log');
   if not Assigned(FStreamWriter) then
   begin
      FStreamWriter := TStreamWriter.Create(lName); // Or TStreamWriter.Create(lName,true);
      FStreamWriter.AutoFlush := true;
   end;
   FStreamWriter.WriteLine(TcxEventDescription(AEvent));
   // Next does not help either:
   FStreamWriter.Flush;
end;
```

Until I call FStreamWriter.Free the file remains 0 bytes.

Comment: Note StreamReader/StreamWrite also support OwnStream to own the Stream, else by default when a stream is passed to their constructor they don't get to own it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TStreamWriter flushing means it will just write its buffer to the attached stream. This does not necessary mean that any TFileStream will flush its OS buffers, just because the TStreamWriter doesn't know of any TFileStream (only TStream).

To make it worse, you are giving a TFileStream instance created by your own. So TStreamWriter doesn't take ownership of the stream and thus will not free it on Destroy. The freeing of the stream would however close the file and thus write the content to disk.

Comment: Yep, I'd just figured that out, but you wrote faster than I did. :-) I've gone back to update the linked post to use a different constructor that gives ownership of the `TFileStream` to the `TStreamWriter` instead. Also clarified the way `AutoFlush` works.

Comment: Interesting. Now that you write this - of course. However, it still does not flush. I now have TStreamWriter.Create(filename) and the file remains 0 bytes until the TStreamWriter.Free. No AutoFlush or Flush helps.

Comment: That is because the internal filestream buffers on its own. The stream writer has no influence on that. If you want an unbuffered filestream you have to write your own implementation of it.

Comment: That makes we want to go back to old-fashioned TTextFile I/O. It's only for logging/debugging purposes where I want to make sure that my log info is all flushed to disk before the program hangs. Does XE2 have more modern file/stream objects that allow me to do this easily?

Comment: If it is only for logging/debugging I suggest using CodeSite.

Comment: Flushing does not even work with old-fashioned file I/O - I'll make that a new question