# How to write a text file as fast as possible in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using this code to save/write a plain-text file:

```
var
  i: int64;
  myFile : TextFile;
  bytes: int64;
begin
  AssignFile(myFile, FileName);
  ReWrite(myFile);
  CloseFile(myFile);

  Append(myFile);    
  bytes:=1073741824; // 1GB
  i:=1;
  while (i<=bytes) do
  begin
    write(myFile, 'a');
    inc(i);
  end;
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

It perfectly creates the test file. However it takes a lot of time. It may be acceptable for HDD drives but it is very slow for NVMe SSD drives.

How can I make this code faster?

Comment: Writing one character at a time will be painfully slow, as you've discovered.  We can only guess that you don't actually need a 1GB file filled with the letter 'a',  so what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  There's no "one way" to do this - there will be many options whose suitability will depend on the actual workflow you're trying to implement.

Comment: Consider this `outStr := StringOfChar('a', bytes div 2);  write(myFile, outStr);  write(myFile, outStr);`.  This completes for me in 18 seconds (10850K, NVMe SSD) because the data is written out in two contiguous blocks instead of one billion individual writes.  A single string can't hold a billion characters but it can hold half that - in any case, the point is that organizing your data in memory **before** you write to disk will save you a lot of time over writing the data out one char at a time.

Comment: Also, ditch the legacy file I/O functions - those are ancient and are also killing your performance.  The same strategy as above takes only 3 seconds when using a [TFileStream and a TStreamWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13306752/327083).

Comment: @J... Wow, it is 50 times faster now. Thank you!